# Arbitrage Bot error: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance

Tags: solidity, flash-loans

I'm building a arbitrage trading bot with solidity. The bot should: see an opportunity on the market, execute a flashloan, swap the token retrieved from the loan for another token, swap that token to pay back the flashloan and keep the profit. But there is a problem, when i test it on remix, the flashloan executes perfectly but it fails right after giving me this error:

> The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
> Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
> Debug the transaction to get more information.

The function that seems to fail is the "executeTrade()" function. If you have any suggestion that would help a lot, im stuck on this bug for a week now and i really dont know what to do. Here's the full contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

interface Structs {
    struct Val {
        uint256 value;
    }

    enum ActionType {
        Deposit, // supply tokens
        Withdraw, // borrow tokens
        Transfer, // transfer balance between accounts
        Buy, // buy an amount of some token (externally)
        Sell, // sell an amount of some token (externally)
        Trade, // trade tokens against another account
        Liquidate, // liquidate an undercollateralized or expiring account
        Vaporize, // use excess tokens to zero-out a completely negative account
        Call // send arbitrary data to an address
    }

    enum AssetDenomination {
        Wei // the amount is denominated in wei
    }

    enum AssetReference {
        Delta // the amount is given as a delta from the current value
    }

    struct AssetAmount {
        bool sign; // true if positive
        AssetDenomination denomination;
        AssetReference ref;
        uint256 value;
    }

    struct ActionArgs {
        ActionType actionType;
        uint256 accountId;
        AssetAmount amount;
        uint256 primaryMarketId;
        uint256 secondaryMarketId;
        address otherAddress;
        uint256 otherAccountId;
        bytes data;
    }

    struct Info {
        address owner; // The address that owns the account
        uint256 number; // A nonce that allows a single address to control many accounts
    }

    struct Wei {
        bool sign; // true if positive
        uint256 value;
    }
}

abstract contract DyDxPool is Structs {
    function getAccountWei(Info memory account, uint256 marketId)
        public
        view
        virtual
        returns (Wei memory);

    function operate(Info[] memory, ActionArgs[] memory) public virtual;

    ActionType actionTest = ActionType.Call;
    AssetDenomination assetTest = AssetDenomination.Wei;
    AssetReference refTest = AssetReference.Delta;
}

contract DyDxFlashLoan is Structs {
    DyDxPool pool = DyDxPool(0x1E0447b19BB6EcFdAe1e4AE1694b0C3659614e4e);

    address public WETH = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
    mapping(address => uint256) public currencies;

    constructor() {
        currencies[WETH] = 1;
    }

    modifier onlyPool() {
        require(
            msg.sender == address(pool),
            "FlashLoan: could be called by DyDx pool only"
        );
        _;
    }

    function tokenToMarketId(address token) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 marketId = currencies[token];
        require(marketId != 0, "FlashLoan: Unsupported token");
        return marketId - 1;
    }

    // the DyDx will call `callFunction(address sender, Info memory accountInfo, bytes memory data) public` after during `operate` call
    function flashloan(
        address token,
        uint256 amount,
        bytes memory data
    ) internal {
        IERC20(token).approve(address(pool), amount + 1);
        Info[] memory infos = new Info[](1);
        ActionArgs[] memory args = new ActionArgs[](3);

        infos[0] = Info(address(this), 0);

        AssetAmount memory wamt = AssetAmount(
            false,
            AssetDenomination.Wei,
            AssetReference.Delta,
            amount
        );
        ActionArgs memory withdraw;
        withdraw.actionType = ActionType.Withdraw;
        withdraw.accountId = 0;
        withdraw.amount = wamt;
        withdraw.primaryMarketId = tokenToMarketId(token);
        withdraw.otherAddress = address(this);

        args[0] = withdraw;

        ActionArgs memory call;
        call.actionType = ActionType.Call;
        call.accountId = 0;
        call.otherAddress = address(this);
        call.data = data;

        args[1] = call;

        ActionArgs memory deposit;
        AssetAmount memory damt = AssetAmount(
            true,
            AssetDenomination.Wei,
            AssetReference.Delta,
            amount + 1
        );
        deposit.actionType = ActionType.Deposit;
        deposit.accountId = 0;
        deposit.amount = damt;
        deposit.primaryMarketId = tokenToMarketId(token);
        deposit.otherAddress = address(this);

        args[2] = deposit;

        pool.operate(infos, args);
    }
}

contract Arbitrage is DyDxFlashLoan {
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uRouter;
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable sRouter;

    address public owner;

    constructor(address _uRouter, address _sRouter) payable {
        uRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_uRouter);
        sRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_sRouter);
        owner = msg.sender;
        (bool success, ) = WETH.call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(success, "fail to get weth");
    }

    function executeTrade(
        address _tokenA,
        address _tokenB,
        uint _tokensFromFlashLoan,
        bool _startOnUniswap
    ) external {
        uint balanceBefore = IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(_tokenA);
        bytes memory data = abi.encode(
            _startOnUniswap,
            _tokenA,
            _tokenB,
            _tokensFromFlashLoan,
            balanceBefore
        );
        flashloan(_tokenA, _tokensFromFlashLoan, data);
    }

    function callFunction(
        address,
        Info calldata,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external onlyPool {
        (
            bool _startOnUniswap,
            address _tokenA,
            address _tokenB,
            uint256 _tokensFromFlashLoan,
            uint256 balanceBefore
        ) = abi.decode(data, (bool, address, address, uint256, uint256));
        uint balanceAfter = IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(address(this));

        require(
            balanceAfter - balanceBefore == _tokensFromFlashLoan,
            "Didn't receive flash loan"
        );

        address[] memory tokens;
        if (_startOnUniswap == true) {
            tokens[0] = _tokenA;
            tokens[1] = _tokenB;

            swapOnUniswap(_tokensFromFlashLoan, 10, tokens);

            tokens[0] = _tokenB;
            tokens[1] = _tokenA;

            swapOnSushiswap(
                IERC20(tokens[0]).balanceOf(address(this)),
                10,
                tokens
            );
        } else {
            tokens[0] = _tokenA;
            tokens[1] = _tokenB;

            swapOnSushiswap(_tokensFromFlashLoan, 10, tokens);

            tokens[0] = _tokenB;
            tokens[1] = _tokenA;

            swapOnUniswap(
                IERC20(tokens[0]).balanceOf(address(this)),
                10,
                tokens
            );
        }
    }

    function swapOnUniswap(
        uint _amountIn,
        uint _amountOut,
        address[] memory _path
    ) internal {
        // swapExactTokensForTokes
        // mettiamo dentro un input token e riceviamo un output token
        // controllare se il token è effetivamente un token
        require(
            IERC20(_path[0]).approve(address(uRouter), _amountIn),
            "Uniswap failed the approval"
        );

        // swappiamo i token e li riceve lo smart contract
        uint[] memory amounts = uRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            _amountIn,
            _amountOut,
            _path,
            address(this),
            (block.timestamp + 1200)
        );
        require(
            amounts[1] == IERC20(_path[0]).balanceOf(address(this)),
            "Didn't receive tokens from swap"
        );
    }

    function swapOnSushiswap(
        uint _amountIn,
        uint _amountOut,
        address[] memory _path
    ) internal {
        require(
            IERC20(_path[0]).approve(address(sRouter), _amountIn),
            "Sushiswap failed the approval"
        );

        uint[] memory amounts = uRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            _amountIn,
            _amountOut,
            _path,
            address(this),
            (block.timestamp + 1200)
        );

        require(
            amounts[1] == IERC20(_path[0]).balanceOf(address(this)),
            "Didn't receive tokens from swap"
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your `executeTrade` the function is expecting a payable modifier,  it expects Ether to be sent along with the transaction, also you are calling the WETH contract and sending the entire value (msg.value) with the transaction but it might leave the contract with zero Ether balance.

I have modified your code like this, it should work:

```
// ... (rest of the code remains unchanged)

contract Arbitrage is DyDxFlashLoan {
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uRouter;
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable sRouter;

    address public owner;

    constructor(address _uRouter, address _sRouter) payable {
        uRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_uRouter);
        sRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_sRouter);
        owner = msg.sender;
        (bool success, ) = WETH.call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(success, "fail to get weth");
    }

    function executeTrade(
        address _tokenA,
        address _tokenB,
        uint _tokensFromFlashLoan,
        bool _startOnUniswap
    ) external payable { // Add the payable modifier here
        uint balanceBefore = IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(_tokenA);
        bytes memory data = abi.encode(
            _startOnUniswap,
            _tokenA,
            _tokenB,
            _tokensFromFlashLoan,
            balanceBefore
        );
        flashloan(_tokenA, _tokensFromFlashLoan, data);
    }

    // ... (rest of the code remains unchanged)
}
```